# Tell RequireJS to not minify a file

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

How can I use [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) config OR even [r.js Config](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject) to not minify specific files.

I can disable minification for *all* files with `optimize: 'none'` option. But I don't know how to disable it for a single file.

```
  options: {                                        
      // Do not minify these files: 
      // 'jquery'
      optimize: 'none', // disables minification for all files
    }
```

I still want the file to be included in the final merged file (unlike `empty:` http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty ), just not passed into uglify.js

Comment: Why is there no answer for this?!?!

Comment: oh, all I needed was `optimize: "none"`

Comment: As `optimize: "none"` is the answer, could someone post it as an answer so @basarat can accept it?

Comment: As `optimize: "none"` is the answer, could someone post it as an answer so @basarat can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a configuration option to disable minification, I have the file excluded from the merged file generated by requirejs and then manually concatenated.

Comment: Did you mean that, the optimization tool by require js can not turn the minification off?

Comment: It can (`optimize: 'none'`), but apparently it's an all-or-nothing thing.

Comment: Yes. So I manually concatenated that file *outside* the workflow of minification